# How to delete a Google Cloud Compute Engine instance within the active instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

How can I delete a Google Cloud Compute Instance from the instance that is to be deleted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the name of the instance is **instance-1** Use the following commands inside the instance:

```
glcoud init
gcloud compute instances delete instance-1
```